# How many blocks in this set differ from the original in one exactly one way?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This is an example problem that I worked out but I'm not sure if it's correct since we weren't given an answer key.

The full problem reads: Dustin has a set of blocks. Each of these blocks is made of either wood or plastic and comes in one of three sizes (small, medium, large), five colors (red, white, blue, yellow, green) and six shapes (triangular, square, rectangular, hexagonal, octagonal, circular).

A. How many blocks does Dustin have if he has a full set, that is one of each possible type.

My answer = 2 types * 3 sizes * 5 colors * 6 shapes = 180

B. (This is the answer I'm not so sure of) How many of the blocks in this set differ from the **small red wooden square** block in **exactly one way**?

My answer = small red (plastic) square = 1 choice

(medium, large) red wooden square = 2 choices

small (white, blue, yellow, green) wooden square = 4 choices

small red wooden (triangular, rectangular, hexagonal, octagonal, circular) = 5 choices

so, 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 = 12 blocks that differ in **exactly one way**

Comment: This is fine. If an attribute has $k$ possible values, then there are $k-1$ ways for it to differ from a specified value. Here $k$ is $2,3,5$, or $6$, depending on the attribute, so $k-1$ is $1,2,4$, or $5$. Finally, summing the possibilities is correct, since each block to be counted differs from the specified block in just one category.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thanks for that explanation. I didn't think about the k - 1 possible values, but I was wondering if there was some type of formula so I will keep that in mind. Thanks

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Brian in the comments,...

Suppose there are $n$ categories, and for the $i$-ith category there are $k_i$ options.

Then the number of sets that differ from a specific set combination, is
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n (k_i-1)$$
In your case this is equal to 1+2+4+5 = 12.

Aggregating all the $1$s together, gives an equivalent expression
$$  \left( \sum_{i=1}^n k_i \right) -n.$$
In your case this is equal to (2+3+5+6)-4 = 12.